# pandas match the best row with the given list

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe "d1" that has "n" columns and "m" rows. I have another dataframe "d2" with one row. My task is to compare the best matching row in d1 when compared with d2 and get the count of matched columns in the d1.

d2:

```
         a                 b      c     d       e
0  machine  machine learning  spark  java  python
```

d1 dataframe is also similar with more rows

```
         a              b        c      d       e
0  machine  deep learning  bigdata   java  python
1      cnn            nlp  bigdata  spark    java
```

when I compare d1 with d2, the best match row is index '0' as it has more matches with d2

As of now, I am iterating the d1 dataframe and comparing it with d2 which is taking lot of time.
Below is the code

```
for index, row in d1.iterrows():
     score = len(set(row.values.tolist()) & set(d2.values[0].tolist()))
     if score >= cutoff_score and score > max_score:
            max_score = sim_score
```

Is there any optimal way to do this comparision in O(1) or O(logn)

Comment: Please provide enough sample data to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iterrows` is a trap. It's basically never the best option, and needlessly overcomplicates things by deconstructing a perfectly good dataframe.

```
d2_set = set(df2.loc[0])
out = df1.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & d2_set), axis=1, raw=True)
print(out)
print(out.idxmax())
```

Output:

```
0    3
1    2
dtype: int64

0
```

---

Given 2,000,000 rows:

```
               a              b        c      d       e
0        machine  deep learning  bigdata   java  python
1            cnn            nlp  bigdata  spark    java
2        machine  deep learning  bigdata   java  python
3            cnn            nlp  bigdata  spark    java
4        machine  deep learning  bigdata   java  python
...          ...            ...      ...    ...     ...
1999995      cnn            nlp  bigdata  spark    java
1999996  machine  deep learning  bigdata   java  python
1999997      cnn            nlp  bigdata  spark    java
1999998  machine  deep learning  bigdata   java  python
1999999      cnn            nlp  bigdata  spark    java

[2000000 rows x 5 columns]
```

It only takes 4 seconds, and then max/idxmax only takes a couple ms:

```
>>> t = time();out = df1.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & d2_set), axis=1, raw=True);time()-t;
4.035001277923584

>>> t = time();out.max();out.idxmax();time()-t;
0.0015015602111816406
```

Your method took about 60 seconds... once I actually got it working, you're missing a lot.

Comment: what is the time complexity of this?

Comment: `.idxmax()` returns the index of the max value, if you want the actual value, just use `.max()`

Comment: `apply` is essentially a for-loop, just more efficient than `iterrows`, And it only needs to calculate what you called `score` on each loop. (Without making a new set for d2 every loop...) Then `idxmax()` and `max()` are vectorized, so I have no idea, but they're very very fast.

Comment: @merkle added some timing info~